# How to configure DNS host record so that my website shows domain name instead of ip address?

Tags: dns, a-records, namecheap

Currently I have a golang app that is serving at X.X.X.X:443. Suppose my domain name is example.com. I want to link example.com to X.X.X.X:443. I tried entering this into A Record but it doesn't allow me to use port. Therefore, I currently use URL Redirect Record. I tried to link CNAME Record to this URL Redirect Record but to no avail. It just keeps showing my ip address instead of example.com.

I don't mind having example.com:443.

Can I know how should I solve this problem? Is it supposed to be solved on the DNS side? Some suggest that I must host on port 80. Is it true?

Comment: Are you hosting yourself this website ?

Comment: @OlivierGaulard yes

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/local-devserver-command)
the parameter to change the host is : **--admin_host=ADMIN_HOST**

Definition is : "Host name to which the local development server's administration console should bind (default: localhost)."